# convert Title to Url Title with unicode characters

Tags: url-title

I'm a Vietnamese. I'm a newbie for ee2. When I enter "Nước ngập mái nhà sau cơn bão" in Title field, EE2 automatically generates "nc-ngp-mai-nha-sau-cn-baeo" in URL Title. That isn't correct. I need "nuoc-ngap-mai-nha-sau-con-bao" in my URL Title. I created my database with "utf8-general-ci" collation. May somebody help me?.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware no. Because EE will strip out the non-alpha numeric characters, not replace them with their similar counterparts. It's not relevant to the Database.

So either you have to manually edit the url_title field each time or look at other options. But in looking elsewhere for solutions may give you an even better end result - of being able to use your language correctly in URLs (better for your users and better for SEO).

I touch briefly on it [here](http://peteralewis.com/blog/expressionengine-multi-language/), but you can utilise a custom field for the url but you can't then use the native and automatic method of channel:entries, so will need to use search:custom_url="nước-ngập-mái-nhà-sau-cơn-bão" dynamic="no" parameters in the channel entries tag.  Your URL would then look something like this:

```
www.mysite.com/content/nước-ngập-mái-nhà-sau-cơn-bão
```

With the 'content' group, index.php template catching this URL.

Alternatively (although I've not had the chance to use it), the [Publisher add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher) allows for multi-language URLs, so this should simplify the whole process if your budget can stretch.

Comment: What addon do you use for tab SEO in this picture (http://peteralewis.com/images/uploads/blog/Fields_side-by-side_3.png). Thanks.

Comment: I don't - they're custom fields meta-title-en, meta-title-ar (for Arabic), etc. I've customised the publish layout to put them side by side and set to RTL. In the EE templates the fields are referred to dynamically using a global variable: {meta-title-{language}} - but setting up for multi-language is a whole other question! If you don't have multi-language it's even easier. There are other add-on options: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/surgeeo, http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/seolite, http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nsm-better-meta to name a few.

Comment: I often create 3 channel fields in each my channel for 3 tag SEO (title, keywords, descriptions). I need a addon that create 3 field (SEO) for all my channels. Thanks.

Comment: You could have a single field group for all your channels, therefore only having 3 meta fields that are shared across all channels. You then hide and show the other fields as relevant to the channel as needed. Albeit the labels and descriptions would need to be worded correctly for the generic fields.